# How to allow file types jpg, jpeg png, doc, docx, zip and pdf in lf-ng-md-file-input

Tags: angularjs, material-design

How to allow file types jpg, jpeg png, doc, docx, zip and pdf in lf-ng-md-file-input
I have tried below code:

```
<lf-ng-md-file-input lf-browse-label="Upload Document" lf-files="document" custom-mimetype="image/*,application/zip,application/pdf,application/kswps,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" lf-api="docApi" lf-filesize="5MB" name="document" drag></lf-ng-md-file-input>
```

But it's not working in zip extension.

Answer (score 0):

**Forbid for selecting zip files**

use accept property to forbid users to select zip files.

```
<lf-ng-md-file-input accept="application/zip" lf-filesize="5MB" name="document" drag></lf-ng-md-file-input>
```

**Validate for selected zip files**

use lf-mimetype property to validate whether the user selected zip files.

```
<lf-ng-md-file-input name="files00" lf-required lf-mimetype="image/*,application/zip" multiple drag preview></lf-ng-md-file-input>
```

**Update**

I have make a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UwsPSSxXyiJtHvg29yi0?p=preview), you can edit and try for it.

**Note**

I have get the latest version of lf-ng-md-file-input(1.5.1) from github, and didn't find a directive named custom-mimetype.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
We have tried but it's not working. can you please check once again with zipping files.

Comment: check the plunker again please. I have make two brief branches. after selected a zip file, the form will show a message of 'mimetype error' .